# how to implement dynamic routes from the server without it failing on refresh?

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

my application's permissions comes dynamically from the server, so the natural implementation i thought about is modify the router tree (using Router.config) before i press any item's url in my navigation bar .
here is my setRoutes function after i get the data from the server before i press any item on navigation bar:

```
setRoutes ( data ) {

data.map ( module => {
module.menus.map ( menu => {
            menu.programs.map ( program => {
                programs.push (
                    {
                        moduleCode : module.code ,
                        menuCode : menu.code ,
                        programCode : program.code ,
                        programLabel : program.dsc,
                        formType: program.formType
                    }
                );
            } );
        } );
    } );
});

  let children = programs.filter(program => program.formType == 'DynamicForm').map ( program => {
        if(program.formType == "DynamicForm"){
        return {
            path : program.programCode ,
            children : [
                {
                    path : "edit" ,
                    component : UpdateRecordComponent,
                    data : { program : program }
                } , {
                    path : "queryForm" ,
                    component : DynamicProgramComponent ,
                    data : { program : program }
                } , {
                    path : "add" ,
                    component : AddRecordComponent ,
                    data : { program : program }
                } , {
                    path : "" ,
                    redirectTo : "queryForm"
                }
            ]
        };
    }

    } );
this.router.config.forEach ( route => {
        if ( route.path === "app" ) {
            route.children.forEach ( child => {
                if ( child.path === "main" ) {
                    child.children = [...child.children , ...children];
                }
            } );
        }
    } );
```

All is good if i entered the app step by step(log in => fill routes and navigation => press and navigate to certain page)

My problem is when i refresh the page at a certain page or try to access it via link.. the router tree gets empty and the app throws an error (Cannot match any routes to URL segment) before i can execute any code like setting the routes first before url event starts.

i tried using APP_INITIALIZER but the Router service or any custom service is undefined when i try to execute the code in the APP_INITIALIZER service

is there any solution to my problem in angular

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dynamic routes, you could use [angular route guards](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards). Espicially look at the canActivate.

canActivate, can be called for every route or child routes, and expects a boolean or Observable which returns a boolean.

This way, what you would do is, have a list of routes already defined. In your route gurad, you can fetch permissions initially from server and store them locally (perhaps local storage), and then test if user is allowed to access that route.

Comment: I get what you're suggesting...the problem is that the navigation bar might change entirely from the database (depending on what programs the client bought or what permissions does the specific user have on the system). having every route hard coded in the project is something i was trying to avoid

Comment: Perhaps, then, use the same data source in navigation bar and your route guards?

Comment: can you illustrate more on what you mean?

Comment: When the user gets logged in, fetch menu data, and store this somewhere maybe local storage. In your route guard when you have current url, test if this url existed in any of the navigation menus (or read from your storage), let the user access the url if it did, else no. Did i explain this enough?

Comment: ahh yes ...thank you zonaib... if i didnt find any conveniant solution while keeping the routes dynamic. i'm going to use your suggestion for solving the problem